# `msdia80.dll` is installed in the root folders of two drives

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, visual-c++

I have 2 HD partitions as `C:` and `D:`, and `msdia80.dll` is present in the root folders of both drives. I have read the [article by Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927665) about this issue, but there is no `VC` folder in my PC under `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\`. How can I solve this problem?

My OS is Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (upgraded from Windows Vista Home Premium 64-bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install "Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)" as Microsoft suggested but right after I confirmed the license agreement, the installer disappeared and nothing happened. I tried this a few times after restarting PC but to no avail. Then I uninstalled the package together with its updates and installed version 2008 ([Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=BD2A6171-E2D6-4230-B809-9A8D7548C1B6&displaylang=en)). Now `msdia80.dll` is gone from the root and `msdia90.dll` is present in the right directory, namely `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VC`.

Comment: I followed this advice, but it only lead to 24 new files appearing in the root of my secondary partition...

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Copy the file to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VC` as suggested.
2. Start a command prompt as administrator and execute commands below:

   `regsvr32 /u C:\msdia80.dll`

   `regsvr32 /u D:\msdia80.dll`
3. Then register the DLL:

   `regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VC\msdia80.dll"`

At least that worked for me.

Comment: Found that folder ```VC``` did not exist. Created the folder first before following the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

You've already solved the problem by finding this support article.

The article says that the VC directory is the right place for these files. However, the problem you have is that they are not placed where they should be, which is why you don't have the right directory.

Best follow the directions as given in the article, and install the SP1 Redistributable Package that's quoted in the article. The article says in your case (64-bits) to download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=747AAD7C-5D6B-4432-8186-85DF93DD51A9). Or just run Windows Update.